# Indesign CC, combine paragraph and character styles into one palette

Tags: adobe-indesign, paragraph-styles, character-styles

Is there a way to combine paragraph and character styles into the same palette of styles? It would make navigating and applying styles easier, instead of continually moving between the paragraph and character style palettes, particularly when multiple style groups are created.

Answer (score 2):

User can drag and drop panels beside or stack-on eachother (where a thick straight blue line appears) to make larger panel groups, those groups will then slidable and could be open together.
Maybe it'll make your procedure faster.

Comment: Additionally, once you have the panels arranged how you like, you can save the configuration as a custom workspace under: Window>Workspace>New Workspace...

Comment: I am probably mistaken, but I recall seeing one panel with both paragraph and character styles.

Comment: @Steve  I suggested that I guess, it must be shown that way! is there any problem?

Comment: It's not really a problem as much as it is an inconvenience. I tried dragging a character style into the paragraph style panel and it shows an X in a circle. I'm a minor power user. As a designer, I don't do the fancy indesign stuff regularly, but I manage to use para/char styles as fully as a I can. Keeps documents moving along, particularly when there's a gap in time on a bigger project. I never leave a smidgen of type on a doc that isn't tied to a style sheet -- which makes for a deep, often confusing, set of Styles.
There's an answer out there somewhere.
Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: @Steve I didn't mean drag n' drop styles theirselves, I meant to drop Panels (UI elements) on or beside eachother. There was a misunderstanding I guess.

Comment: Not a problem [or course!].